# Node.js - undefined variable after assignment in fs functions

Tags: node.js, undefined, fs

stackoverflow!
I am fairly new to node.js, and this seems to be node-specific. I keep defining a variable and I get errors that `fileName` is `undefined`. I have no idea why this is happening because, from my perspective, I'm just assigning a global variable inside a function, and that should work in all other programming languages I've worked in. Does the argument function in `fs.readFile()` somehow differ from a normal function? I honestly have no idea. Anyways, this is my full code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dateObject = new Date();
var fileName;

function Start() {
   fs.readFile('./counter.txt', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var current = parseInt(data);
        current++;
        fs.writeFile('./counter.txt', current.toString(), function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Written!");
        });
        var fullDate = `${dateObject.getDate()}-${dateObject.getMonth() + 1}-${dateObject.getFullYear()}`;
        fileName = `./logs/${fullDate} ${current}.txt`;
        console.log(fileName);
        fs.appendFile(fileName, "Logger Initiated!", function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
        })
    });
}


function PAL (text) {
    if (fileName === undefined) {
        console.log("...");
        return "500";
    }
    console.log(fileName);
    fs.appendFile(fileName, text, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
}



module.exports = {Start, PAL};
```

Another file:

```
const logger = require('./logger')
// ....
app.listen(port, () => {
logger.Start();
logger.PAL("test");
})
```

Comment: You have _declared_ fileName, but you haven't assigned it any value. Until it has a value, a JavaScript variable's contents are `undefined`.

Comment: @samuei fileName = `./logs/${fullDate} ${current}.txt`;

Comment: you don't show how you are calling PAL() or Start().  i imagine calling PAL() first would break, because fileName hasn't yet been initialized.  it only gets initialized halfway through Start()...

Comment: I first run Start(); and then PAL();, edited

Answer (score 0):

You got an asynchronous trap in code, fs.readFile is an async function, so when you run .PAL, I think you expected .Start function done, but it's not true. Start function:

```js
async function Start() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('./counter.txt', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw reject(err);
            var current = parseInt(data);
            current++;
            fs.writeFile('./counter.txt', current.toString(), function(err) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                console.log("Written!");
                var fullDate = `${dateObject.getDate()}-${dateObject.getMonth() + 1}-${dateObject.getFullYear()}`;
                fileName = `./logs/${fullDate} ${current}.txt`;
                console.log("FILENAME: ", fileName);
                fs.appendFile(fileName, "Logger Initiated!", function(err){
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    resolve();
                })
            });
        });
    })
}
```

Call: `logger.Start().then(() => logger.PAL("test"));`

Comment: It works now! Thanks. there is one slight issue - I don't want to run Start() each time I use PAL(), and PAL() by itself doesn't work